# iOS: split uiview with other ViewController view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to make something like iPad setting screen but in a subview on my controller.. so I can't use UISplitViewController

i've made a subview with 2 subviews the left one is tablevew the right one is normal view to subview the controller i want to add in it.

I'm using this snippet for that

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController * vc  = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
vc.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;
[self.customView addSubview:vc.view];
```

But it crashes with error

> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated

instance now after i enabled zombie obj

Can anyone figure out why is this happen or even better is there an open source component that can do this ?

Comment: How can it crash with no error? Nothing returns at all? No messages?

Comment: No error? You mean the IDE? Your binary won't crash without an error of some kind down in the console.

Comment: yes.. I think it's a problem regarding a tableview in this controller.. it gives 
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance
now after i enabled zombie obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little extra work which needs to be done for a view controller which [contains a sub view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController * vc  = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];

[self addChildViewController:vc]; // Before adding the subview

vc.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;
[self.customView addSubview:vc.view];

[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self]; // After adding the subview
```

Comment: I kinda got it myself but that a good answer :) 
but i have a question ..
what is the user of didMoveToParentViewController

Comment: `-willMoveToParentViewController:` and `-didMoveToParentViewController:` are messages which need to be sent when adding a child to a parent. This is similar to `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:`. NOTE: `-addChildViewController:` sends the child `-willMoveToParentViewController:`, so you only need to send `-didMoveToParentViewController:`.